# y position animate in if statement

Tags: html, if-statement, jquery-animate

So i'm making a tiny html5 game. And I don't know how to formulate something.

I've got this:

```
if (40 in keysDown) { // Player holding down
    hero.y = 300;
}
```

So if players hold down the arrow key, the hero jumps to 300px. But I want it to animate to 300px, how do I do that?

I've tried this:

```
if (40 in keysDown) { // Player holding down
        hero.animate({"top", "300px"}); 
}
```

But this doesn't work. I think it's possible, I just don't know how to formulate this.

Comment: What have you tried? You mention `jquery-animate` in your tags. Did you already try to used this? If yes what did not work?

Comment: We have no idea what your `hero` object is or does …

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are setting the y position to 300, use the following code instead

```
hero.y += 300;
```

Comment: Sorry my answer was abit incomplete, it dissapears because it adds 300px to the current position. For realistic movement you should use a game loop, this is a great beginner's article http://www.lostdecadegames.com/how-to-make-a-simple-html5-canvas-game/